# Programmatically create a paragraph entity reference field

Tags: 8, entities, paragraphs

I need to create a config page, that is able to add social media information ( name and icon ), the user must be able to add as many social medias as it wants. To do so, I'we created a paragraph with two fields: name & icon, then I want to add this paragraph as an entity reference field programmaticaly in my config page, the paragraph machine name is social_media.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['social_media_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Social Media Configuration'),
      '#collapsible' => TRUE,
      '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    ];

    $field = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Type'))
      ->setDescription(t('The Paragraphs type.'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'paragraph')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setSetting('handler_settings',['target_bundles'=>
                      ['social_media'=>'social_media']
          ]);

    $form['social_media'] = $field;

    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }
```

the page is shown but without a form:

[image]

Comment: There's no `entityreference` element type - maybe you meant `entity_autocomplete`?

Comment: not entity_autocomplete, i edited my question it's entity_reference of type paragraph, and the paragraph id is social_media

Comment: Are you talking about an entity reference field attached to an entity type? That’s a different thing, you can’t use it in a custom form, it only applies to an entity form

Comment: yes, that's exactly it, so it's not possible to create an entity reference field attached to a paragraph entity type in a custom form, i would appreciate if there is another solution to achieve this

Comment: That’s right, by definition a form widget for an entity field can only be used on a form built for the related entity. Seems counter intuitive until you get under the hood, it does make sense. I’d assume whatever you’re building will have to be manually coded

Comment: Can you check this topic about Creating a content entity type in Drupal 8 ? -  https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/entity-api/creating-a-content-entity-type-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code did the trick for me when adding the field to custom entity. This provides a reference to the paragraph and the revision. Just to note out that when the paragraph is edited, the reference field will still refer to the old revision. The field type is **entity_reference_revisions** and my paragraph type

```
$fields['social_media_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference_revisions')
  ->setLabel(t('Skill'))
  ->setDescription(t('The ID of the skill'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default:paragraph')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['social_media' => 'social_media']])
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['negate' => 0])
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
    'weight' => 5,
    'settings' => [
      'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
      'size' => '60',
      'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
      'placeholder' => '',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses the Paragraphs Classic widget for the form display and allows to add as many paragraph items as you need

```
$fields['my_paragraph'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference_revisions')
  ->setLabel(t('My paragraph'))
  ->setDescription(t('My paragraph description.'))
  ->setCardinality(-1)
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('target_type', 'paragraph')
  ->setSetting('handler', 'default:paragraph')
  ->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['my_paragraph' => 'my_paragraph']])
  ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'entity_reference_paragraphs',
    'weight' => 12,
    'settings' => [
      'title' => 'Paragraph',
      'title_plural' => 'Paragraphs',
      'edit_mode' => 'open',
      'add_mode' => 'dropdown',
      'form_display_mode' => 'default',
      'default_paragraph_type' => '',
    ],
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

Comment: No `->save();` in the end, is this right?

Comment: I use the code to create fields for a custom entity (function baseFieldDefinitions) so I just need to return $fields.