How to make a Paragraphs entity Reference Field in Custom Entity
I've created a custom entity in a custom module and one of the fields on this entity is an entity reference field to a Paragraphs typed entity. The field is created just fine and i can even 'add' a new instance of the custom entity, however when i try to edit the entity the paragraph reference field fails, giving me an error. I get a different error depending on the widget that is selected for the paragraph entity reference field.
If i use an inline entity form based widget I get a Drupal message that This entity (paragraph:37) cannot be reference. in a Drupal message.
If I use a paragraph stable or legacy widget type, I get the error directly in the edit field area without needing to save first that says, You are not allowed to add any of the Paragraphs types.
I am the site admin user and have verified full rights to everything in the permissions tab.
System Versions:

Drupal 10.3.6
Paragraphs 8.x-1.18

To Recreate the Error
Create a Paragraph Type to reference

Make sure Paragraphs module is installed, I'm using
Create new Paragraph Type called test_plain
Add a basic plain text field to the test_plain paragraph type

Create Custom Entity and Module
I used the devel module's drush generate entity:content to make a base scaffolding for a new content entity.

From command line use drush generate entity:content
answer questions being sure to adding translatable and revisionable

Module machine name: cont_ent_test
Module name [Cont ent test]:
Entity type label [Cont ent test]:
Entity type ID [cont_ent_test]:
Entity class [ContEntTest]:
Entity base path [/cont-ent-test]:
Make the entity type fieldable? [Yes]:
Make the entity type revisionable? [No]: Yes
Make the entity type translatable? [No]: Yes
The entity type has bundle? [No]:
Create canonical page? [Yes]:
Create entity template? [Yes]:
Create CRUD permissions? [No]:
Add "label" base field? [Yes]:
Add "status" base field? [Yes]:
Add "created" base field? [Yes]:
Add "changed" base field? [Yes]:
Add "author" base field? [Yes]:
Add "description" base field? [Yes]: No
Create REST configuration for the entity? [No]:



Update the cont_ent_test Entity With Paragraph Entity Reference Field
Finally we add the paragraph entity reference field to the new custom entity.
// We get the available paragraph entities and make sure we have a `test_plain` entity
$paragraph_types = \Drupal::service('entity_type.bundle.info')->getBundleInfo('paragraph');
foreach ($paragraph_types as $id => $type_info) {

  $field_id = 'test_plain';
  if ($id == $field_id) {
    $fields['test_plains'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference_revisions')
      ->setLabel(t('Test Plain'))
      ->setRequired(FALSE)
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setCardinality(BaseFieldDefinition::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'paragraph')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default:paragraph')
      ->setSetting('handler_settings', [
        'target_bundles' => [$field_id],
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'inline_entity_form_complex',
        // 'settings' => [
        //   'form_mode' => 'default',  // Use default form mode for paragraphs
        //   'label_singular' => t(ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $field_id))),
        //   'label_plural' => t(ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $field_id)).'s'),
        //   'override_labels' => TRUE,
        // ],
        'weight' => 30,
      ])
      // ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
      //   'type' => 'entity_reference_revisions',
      //   'label' => 'above',
      //   'weight' => 30,
      // ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE)
    ;
  }

} // END - foreach(paragraph type entity)

Add/Edit Instance of New Cont Ent Test Entity
Install the new module which will be in the '@to do Add Package' section of the Extend page.
Go to Content -> Cont Ent Test the click Add button to create a new instance. Add a Test Plain paragraph in the nested field, and save the instance.


After saving we can go back and try to edit form.


Without changing anything if we try to save from the edit form we get an error.


If I use a Paragraph type widget then I get this error directly in the paragraph field

The user is the full site admin to everything. For completeness, here is the ContEntTestInterface, which is what is created by the drush generate.
\\ src\ContEntTestInterface.php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Drupal\cont_ent_test;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityChangedInterface;
use Drupal\user\EntityOwnerInterface;

/**
 * Provides an interface defining a cont ent test entity type.
 */
interface ContEntTestInterface extends ContentEntityInterface, EntityOwnerInterface, EntityChangedInterface {

}

Content Type Entity Works
To verify the issue is not with the paragraph entity type, i also created a new Node type (ie content type) via the Drupal Admin interface and added the test_plain paragraph entity ref field to it via the admin UI Manage fields and it works fine. So there is something that enables the paragraphs and node entities to work together that my custom entity is missing, but I can't figure out what it is. The revisioning, translatable, and access seem to be the same from what I can tell.

I don't think an entity reference revisions field can be a base field. Base fields are primitive single value columns. An ERR field like paragraphs needs 2 columns, the id and the revision_id.

Is this a field level revision that is in addition to the entity being revisionable? The custom entity def is extended from RevisionableContentEntityBase. For the field type to try for paragraph entity ref i got from this stack answer, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/275551/104691, but that could be wrong. They mention something about the rev on edit, but it's not clear to me what they mean. That could be the same thing I'm seeing. What field class should I try that might be more compatible with a paragraph type?

ER (entity reference, e.g. terms, media, user,...) is a single value. Saving the host does not generate a new revision for the linked entity. The linked entity is a standalone unit. Paragraphs is an ERR (entity reference revision): These are strictly tied to their one single host, and saving the host will create a new revision for the linked paragraph too.

I guess I'm confused, I'm using entity_reference_revisions as the field type. Are you saying that the issue is that I'm doing this as part of a baseFieldDefnition() with a BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_refrence_revisions') and that base fields can't handle this field type?

Yes, I think so (not tested though, more guessing to be honest)

@Hudri, I believe you are correct. Instead of using the baseFieldDefinition() to define this field. I was able to do it successfully by creating a configurable field with some yml files in my custom entity module config/install, similar to what is done here, https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/entity-api/programming-custom-fields-into-your-content-type and this works, THANKS! I will add the solution as an answer.

Solution: Use Configurable Field Definition
Thanks to @Hudri's comments, I was able to resolve the entity reference error for a paragraph entity, by making the field on the custom entity a configurable field instead of using the baseFieldDefinition().
To make the test_plain paragraph reference field on the cont_ent_test entity we create a set of configuration files in the cont_ent_test\config\install\.
modules/custom/cont_ent_test/
├── cont_ent_test.info.yml
├── cont_ent_test.module
└── config/
    └── install/
        ├── field.storage.cont_ent_test.field_test_plains.yml
        ├── field.field.cont_ent_test.default.field_test_plains.yml
        ├── core.entity_form_display.cont_ent_test.default.default.yml
        └── core.entity_view_display.cont_ent_test.default.default.yml

field.storage.cont_ent_test.field_test_plains.yml
Create the field storage configuration.
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - paragraphs
id: field.storage.cont_ent_test.field_test_plains
field_name: field_test_plains
entity_type: cont_ent_test
type: entity_reference_revisions
settings:
  target_type: paragraph
  handler: default
  handler_settings: {}
module: paragraphs
locked: false
cardinality: -1
translatable: true
indexes: {}
persist_with_no_fields: false
custom_storage: false


field.field.cont_ent_test.default.field_test_plains.yml
Define the an instance of this field on the custom cont_ent_test entity.
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  module:
    - paragraphs
  content:
    - cont_ent_test
id: field.field.cont_ent_test.cont_ent_test.field_test_plains
field_name: field_test_plains
entity_type: cont_ent_test
bundle: cont_ent_test
settings: {}
module: paragraphs
locked: false
description: ''
required: false
translatable: true
default_value: []
default_value_callback: ''
field_type: entity_reference_revisions


core.entity_form_display.cont_ent_test.default.default.yml
Configure the Form Display to a complex inline entity form widget
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.field.cont_ent_test.default.field_test_plains
  module:
    - cont_ent_test
id: cont_ent_test.default.default
targetEntityType: cont_ent_test
bundle: default
mode: default
content:
  field_test_plains:
    type: inline_entity_form_complex
    settings:
      form_mode: default
      allow_new: true
      allow_existing: true
      match_operator: CONTAINS
      match_limit: 10
      autocomplete_match: 'default'
      autocomplete_path: ''
      add_mode: 'default'
      edit_mode: 'default'
      cardinality: 1
      override_labels: false
      labels_singular: 'Item'
      labels_plural: 'Items'
    third_party_settings: {  }
hidden: {  }


core.entity_view_display.cont_ent_test.default.default.yml
Configure the View Display Mode
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies:
  config:
    - field.field.cont_ent_test.default.field_test_plains
  module:
    - cont_ent_test
id: cont_ent_test.default.default
targetEntityType: cont_ent_test
bundle: default
mode: default
content:
  field_test_plains:
    label: above
    type: entity_reference_label
    settings: {  }
    third_party_settings: {  }
hidden: {  }

